# data aggregation and averaging on 200 billion records

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-athena, bigdata

The records started out in AVRO files that were created daily with the following schema. There are 20 different attribute types stored in the "attribute_key" and "attribute_value" records, a timestamp, and device_id are also included in each measurement.

```
"fields" : [
{"type":"string", "name":"device_id"},
{"type":"string", "name":"record_date"},
{"type":"string", "name":"attribute_key"},
{"type":"string", "name":"attribute_value"}]
```

I have been able to take the daily files and load them into month seperated tables in bigquery.

```
device_attributes201501
device_attributes201502
device_attributes201503
device_attributes201504
device_attributes201505
device_attributes201506
device_attributes201507
device_attributes201508
device_attributes201509
device_attributes201510
device_attributes201511
device_attributes201512
```

My problem is two-fold,

I need to create a table that consists all of the unique device_ids collected across all time, and the latest attribute value for each value type.

```
   device_id, record_date, attribute_key, attribute_value
   abc123     2015-10-11   attribute_1    5
   abc123     2015-11-11   attribute_1    5
   abc123     2015-12-11   attribute_1    10
   abc123     2015-10-11   attribute_1    0
   abc456     2015-10-11   attribute_1    0
   abc789     2015-10-11   attribute_1    0
   abc123     2015-11-11   attribute_1    0
   abc456     2015-11-11   attribute_1    0
   abc789     2015-11-11   attribute_1    6
   abc123     2015-10-11   attribute_2    blue
   abc123     2015-11-11   attribute_2    red
   abc123     2015-12-11   attribute_2    red
   abc456     2015-12-11   attribute_2    blue
   abc789     2015-12-11   attribute_2    green
```

A weekly, monthly, and 90 day average would also need to be computed for some attributes. (attribute_3 is the average of samples collected)

```
   device_id, last_update, attribute_1, attribute_2
   abc123     2015-12-11   6            red
   abc456     2015-12-11   0            blue
   abc789     2015-12-11   3            green
```

I'm curious how best to take take this on, and I have no idea where to go from here. The data is in bigquery now, I have access to the full suite of google clould tools... like dataflow, or anything else.

The data was originally in an S3 bucket, so I can process it with any of the solutions on AWS.

I just don't know what's the smartest way to go about doing it.

Comment: A BigQuery SQL query should be fine for what you want to do.  Have you had problems with this approach?

Comment: +one for smashing it with SQL in BigQuery.

Comment: BigQuery because you don't have to code much to do basic aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully some of these links will help you. Creating a table
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating-a-table

BigQuery Web UI
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui

How to create a table from a query (blog post from a user). This one suggests that you can use the BQ WebUI and specify a destination table. I couldn't find that in the official docs, so not sure if this works. If not you'll need to setup the API and write a bit of code as shown in their example above.
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-create-a-table-from-a-query-in-google-bigquery/